# How To Display Author Photo In WordPress without any plugin?

Tags: images, user-meta

**How To Display Author Photo In WordPress without any plugin?**

I know there are many plugins in wordpress that give me solution. But I don't want to use any plugin.

**Is there any way to add image for a user in wordpress?**

(That may be any hard code or any database or direct image upload operation).

Comment: Why don't you take a look at one of the many plugins you mentioned, and figure out how to add the relevant code to your functions.php?

Comment: Why don't you use gravatar?

Comment: This is plain plugin territory. In a theme this would be a serious bug.

Comment: Friend Toscho, your comment sounds good. My requirement is to implement in my custom theme, so it dosn't matter for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do this yourself first you'll have to make sure that the form supports `enctype`:

```
/** Add Encryption Type to User Forms to allow Uploads **/
function profile_form_edit( ) {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
add_action( 'user_edit_form_tag' , 'profile_form_edit' );
```

Then you're going to have to add a new field that allows users to upload images and supply feedback in the case an image was unable to upload. The easiest way is to grab the image, let WordPress handle the upload [through](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)<sup>1</sup> [various](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)<sup>2</sup> [functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata)<sup>3</sup>, then save the attachment ID into the database ( [User](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)<sup>1</sup> [Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)<sup>2</sup> ).

There are a bunch of articles on [what metadata is](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-metadata-in-wordpress--cms-21034) and how to [add new usermeta](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-custom-user-profile-fields) - handling the upload can be done in many different ways so it's up to on to figure out what works bests. Hopefully that gets your started and good luck!

Comment: your solution is good, let me check it out